# Centering responsive video background on website in css3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to center video background on website.

On `1920x1080` size everything is ok, but on smaller devices, video isn't centered.

How can i fix this ?

My index.html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>video web</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
    document.createElement('video');
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <a href="mailto:website@videowebsite.com">
        <video autoplay loop poster="images/intro.jpg" id="bgvid" align="middle">
            <!--<source src="video/izba_intro.webm" type="video/webm">-->
            <source src="video/izba_intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
video#bgvid {
    position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; left:0; top: 0; z-index: -100;
    background: url(../images/intro.jpg) center no-repeat;
    width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: auto;
}

video { display: block; display: block;
margin: 0 auto;} 

video#bgvid { transition: 1s opacity; }

.stopfade { opacity: .5; }

/* mobile */

@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    body { 
        background: url(../images/intro.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed; 
    }

    #bgvid { 
        display: none; 
    }
}
```

How I can fix this to get responsive video background ? Is it possible to get this result in pure css3 without writing javascript ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: When you say centered, do you mean letterboxed, or cropped? The former is easy, latter is quite a bit harder, which is why libraries like [bigvideo.js](https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) exist

Comment: I want to only center the video and get result similar to background-size:cover, but for video object. It can be cropped, only center area from video must be visible on smaller devices.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no `background-size: cover` for video, and you need math to emulate the behaviour (which you can't do with CSS). So in your case, you'll need to look at javascript based solutions, or deliver an image to mobile devices instead of video and use `background-size: cover`

Comment: Try to use this Bootstrap's class: [responsive-embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed)

Answer (score 1):

I'll just copy paste my answer from another question, the key here is keeping it centered.

---

**Disclaimer**: *I've only been experimenting with web development (or any sort of code/script) for about 9 months, so don't assume my solution is without fault. See footnote for known issues.*

I've been facing the same problem, and I think I understand exactly what you're looking for.

Basically, regardless of screen width/height, the video's horizontal and vertical edges should never enter the viewport, aspect ratio should be retained and the video should be centered vertically and horizontally.

Example for a video with a **1920x800** resolution:

*(CSS vendor prefixes are missing)

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg-vid-container">
    <video id="bg-vid" class="cover" poster="lib/img/bg-vid.poster.png" autoplay loop>
        <source src="lib/vid/bg-vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg-vid-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

video.cover {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 240vh;
    height: auto;
}
```

---

The flex box model with `justify-content` and `align-items` set to center will keep the video vertically and horizontally centered and `overflow: hidden;` stops unwanted scrolling.

The `min-width` is set in this case to `240vh` (view height unit, where 1vh=1% of window height). This is calculated by scaling the aspect ratio to a height of 100 (I use Andrew Hedges' [Aspect Ratio Calculator](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/)).

1920x800 scales to **240**x100.

This will prevent the video's height from dropping below 100% but still allow it's width to be 100% if the browser window gets that wide, simply increasing its height at that point.

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/), the flex box model and the vh unit both have good support.

This wont work as desired (yet) on mobile seeing as on some devices, the keyboard sliding up resizes the window. I'm working on a jQuery/CSS media query solution to this. I'll update with results if they work as intended. iOS 7's support for vh is also a bit sketchy.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you have to adjust the css containing the video, telling it that the minimum height has to be 100% in both parts. I had a similar issue and I solved it in the following way:

```
#bgvid {
    position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; z-index: -100;
    background: url(../images/intro.jpg) center no-repeat;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; margin: auto;
}
```

I have edited the code with your details. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh; /* stretch to screen height */
}
```